# Expression based Border Style is not working in Excel (.xlsx) export in SSRS 2017

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I am facing issue with expression based Borderstyle and BorderColor in Excel Export only whereas same expression is working as expected in web browser, PDF export and report designer. In Detail row-group, row is using expression based Borderstyle to show border "Solid" or "None" but Excel export is completely omitting the expression.

**for bottom border Color =IIF(Fields!Show_Underline.Value=1,"Black","White")**

**for bottom border  Style =IIF(Fields!Show_Underline.Value=1,"Solid","None")**

Please see below screenshots

**Report Output in web browser, PDF export and report designer**
[image]

**Report Output in EXCEL**

[image]

Sample RDL location:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MgWExAQqUu2QYBaO4mvZ5QoNV16ob0UB/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Here it is.

Select all three cells and then go to border style default as None but at bottom add below expression

```
=IIF(Fields!ShowUnderlin.Value=1,"Solid","None")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you but this is not working for me. i am using SSDT2017 and ReporServer is version is also 2017

Comment: I have the same configuration, probably you are doing something different, do one thing create new tablix and try there.